# How was the poem "The Pardah Nashin" received by critics and the general public?

Tags: poetry, reception, sarojini-naidu

I've been reading the poem [*The Pardah Nashin*](https://allpoetry.com/The-Pardah-Nashin) from the book [*The Golden Threshold*](https://books.google.it/books?id=ULjZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT4) by Sarojini Naidu:

> HER life is a revolving dream 
> Of languid and sequestered ease; 
> Her girdles and her fillets gleam 
> Like changing fires on sunset seas; 
> Her raiment is like morning mist, 
> Shot opal, gold and amethyst. 
> From thieving light of eyes impure, 
> From coveting sun or wind's caress, 
> Her days are guarded and secure 
> Behind her carven lattices, 
> Like jewels in a turbaned crest, 
> Like secrets in a lover's breast.  
> But though no hand unsanctioned dares  
> Unveil the mysteries of her grace, 
> Time lifts the curtain unawares, 
> And Sorrow looks into her face... 
> Who shall prevent the subtle years, 
> Or shield a woman's eyes from tears?

The poem delicately and sensitively portrays the sad existence of a woman who sees the world through a [kind of burkha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purdah). Lots of women live today in similar situations. I imagine it hasn't gone completely unnoticed, so I would like to know how this poem was received by both critics and the general public. What did reviewers or readers said about it?